# How to use GPU for extracting patches from images

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I am looking for a way to extract patches of size `m x n` from a matrix in Matlab by using GPU. The location of the patch extraction is determined by shifting a `m x n` window for `s` pixels horizontally and vertically.

Originally, I solved this problem by just using naive 2 nested for loops. However, it gets slow when I have a large image and small `m` and `n`. Because, this task has to be done multiple times, I want to increase the speed. I thought this process could be done in parallel, so I tried using `parfor` to solve the problem. But, it gets even slower than the normal for loops method.

Right now I am trying to use GPU for helping me in this task. But, currently I have now idea how to implement it. I have checked `arrayfun`, but it seems that it only support for element-wise calculation.

So, is it possible to use GPU to help solving the problem? It seems like it could be done in parallel.

**EDIT: an example to the problem**

Let's say I have a `3 x 3` matrix (I will write the matrix in MATLAB format).

`

```
A = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9];
```

`

I want to extract patches with size of `2 x 2`. And I want the each patches are generated by 1 pixel shift. So, the result should be

```
`p1 = [1 2; 4 5]; p2 = [2 3; 5 6]; p3 = [4 5; 7 8]; p4 = [5 6; 8 9];`
```

And here is an example of what I did in the for loops method.

```
A = magic(3);
patchSize = [2 2];
shift = 1;

finalI = floor((size(A,1) - patchSize(1)) / shift);
finalJ = floor((size(A,2) - patchSize(2)) / shift);
patch = cell(finalI,finalJ);
for i = 0:finalI
    for j = 0:finalJ
        patch{i+1,j+1} = A(1+i*shift : patchSize(1)+i*shift, 1+j*shift : patchSize(2)+j*shift);
    end
end
```

Comment: Firstly, do you actually have a suitable GPU and the Parallel Computing Toolbox?

Comment: Yes, I have checked with gpuDevice command. I also tested most of the example involve using GPU.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a problem that is well-suited for a GPU. I would recommend specifying your problem a little more and we can help you develop a fast vectorized approach.

Comment: @Suever I have edited the post to show some examples.

Comment: The problem is now solved by using im2col as suggested by @rayryeng. I did not realize that im2col was accelerated by GPU as it is not listed as a GPU supported function in https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/gpu-computing.html. However, thank you for help!

Comment: @zynaxsoft I was mistaken.  It is not GPU accelerated.  However, I did find a MEX GPU accelerated version of `im2col` though.  You will need to compile the code with CUDA of course: https://github.com/projectgalateia/im2col_gpu.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check that.